# ImageIO is not loading an image

Tags: java, image, loading

I am have trouble loading an image with java code. I have the image, i.png in the same package as the class this code is in. This is the code.

```
    Image img;
    try
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("i.png"));
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
    }
```

When i execute this code it throws an IOException and says it cannot read the input file.
Would anybody know why it might throw that exception
Sorry for the bad wording
what i ment is the code throws an exception then you obviosly can'nt use it later in the code(Thats what i get for staying up till 11:30)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is an Exception being thrown?

Comment: can you show the piece of code where you try to use the image?

Comment: Maybe a e.printStackTrace() would help in the catch clause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bad practice to hard code paths in your code or keep the resources in the same package just to make the access easy.
You can give either the hard coded path or use the [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

getResourceAsStream's documentation says

> Finds the resource with the given name. A resource is some data (images, audio, text, etc) that can be accessed by class code in a way that is independent of the location of the code.

This is what you want with your code.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream) answer to get a bit more clarity on file way of accessing resources vs classloader way of accessing resources.

So, with some modification your code works when it is changed like this -

```
public class TestIt {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Image img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(TestIt.class.getResourceAsStream( "i.png" ));
img.getGraphics();
System.out.println(img);
}
```

}

Notice the use of getResourceAsStream method.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer exception because your **img** variable stays null after executing 
**img = ImageIO.read(new File("i.png"))**. Because it stays null, you are getting null pointer exception while trying to use it further in the code.

Here is your solution:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("i.png"));
```

Regards,
Ravi